# What is the consequence of chmod 0755 for pkexec

Tags: systemd, polkit

I understand that one way to quickly mitigate CVE-2021-4034 is to chmod 0755 /usr/bin/pkexec (ie remove the SUID bit from it).

I am unclear exactly what the real world consequence of this is.  (And, looking at my Ubuntu 20.04 install this appears to happen when I updated polkit to a version without the bug).

Answer (score 3):

The real-world consequence of removing the setuid bit on `pkexec` is that it stops working for anyone other than root (and root doesn’t need `pkexec`).

One of the first things `pkexec` does is [check that its effective user ID is root](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/-/blob/a2bf5c9c83b6ae46cbd5c779d3055bff81ded683/src/programs/pkexec.c#L517):

```c
  /* check for correct invocation */
  if (geteuid () != 0)
    {
      g_printerr ("pkexec must be setuid root\n");
      goto out;
    }
```

If that’s not the case, it errors out.

The benefit of this mitigation is that `pkexec` stops working for everyone other than root, including malicious actors. But anything relying on `pkexec` and running as non-root will also stop working, so a better solution is to install an updated version (from your distribution, as you’ve done).

If you can’t upgrade, you might as well delete `pkexec` (the binary, not the containing package). Some programs support multiple ways of elevating privileges; if they try `pkexec` first, they will fail if it exists but doesn’t work, whereas they could try another approach if they can’t find it at all.

Comment: Removing the `suid` bit removes its raison d'être. Its whole point is to elevate privileges. You might as well delete it.

Comment: Technically, programs running as root can still use it to run a program as another user, but they don’t need `pkexec` for that in the first place.